# Get list of S3 bucket and add tags to them

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3

In my use case, I am trying to get all the S3 buckets in my account starting with a given name and then adding a tag to all of them. Below is my code (being new to Python, I might have missed something) Once I have created a list of all buckets, I would want to read that back and add tag one by one in them. Currently, I am getting error on the line

> bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging(list[i])

I think, It is not liking the way I am passing the list. Any inputs here would be highly appreciated. Thank you

```
import boto3
list = []
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for bucket in s3.buckets.all(): 
  if bucket.name.startswith("bucketPrefix"):
    list.append(bucket)

for i in range(len(list)):
  bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging(list[i])
  tags = bucket_tagging.tag_set
  tags.append({'Key':'segment', 'Value': 'name'})
  Set_Tag = bucket_tagging.put(Tagging={'TagSet':tags})
```

Comment: What's the error? I tested and no error was raised.
```
>>> bucket_tagging
s3.BucketTagging(bucket_name=s3.Bucket(name='xxxxxxxx'))
```

Comment: File "s3tag.py", line 10, in <module>
    tags = bucket_tagging.tag_set
  File "C:\Users\sasharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 339, in property_loader
    self.load()
   File "C:\Users\sasharma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\botocore\handlers.py", line 231, in validate_bucket_name
    if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Could you try `bucket_tagging = s3.BucketTagging(list[i].name)`?

Comment: This helped but now I am getting this error, botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidTag) when calling the PutBucketTagging operation: Cannot provide multiple Tags with the same key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

for bucket in s3_resource.buckets.all():
    if bucket.name.startswith("prefix"):

        # Extract current tags
        try:
            tag_set = bucket.Tagging().tag_set
        except:
            # No current tags
            tag_set = []

        # Append tag
        tag_to_add = {'Key':'segment', 'Value': 'name'}
        tag_set = [tag for tag in tag_set if tag['Key'] != tag_to_add['Key']]
        bucket.Tagging().put(Tagging={'TagSet':tag_set + [tag_to_add]})
```

Comment: Thanks John for your inputs here. I am getting this error, botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidTag) when calling the PutBucketTagging operation: Cannot provide multiple Tags with the same ke. So on this scenario, I have many buckets starting with a common prefix like xyx-dev, xyz-qa, xyz-prod etc

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to add a tag that already exists (eg a `segment` tag already exists). I've updated the code to have the new tag replace the old tag.

Comment: ok got it John. Is it really required to enable S3 transfer acceleration on buckets to make sure this runs? I have few buckets which has this enabled but few of them are not, I am getting the error botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the PutBucketTagging operation: S3 Transfer Acceleration is disabled on this bucket. 

I tried adding the code around enabling transfer acceleration but its still says the same error s3={"use_accelerate_endpoint": True}

Comment: Quick update : I actually checked my config file and had the 'use_accelerate_endpoint = true' so I removed this and it worked fine. Anyone using the above solution should make sure to remove this parameter from the default profile which is being used for S3 authenticaion.

Comment: The code works fine for my buckets and they do _not_ have Endpoint Acceleration. See if you can narrow-down the code that is causing the problem and you can create another Question.